# Spring autowire list without merging all possible beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I'm using 4.2.0 spring.

I create two beans:

```
@Bean
public String sessionAttributeName() {
    return "someString";
}

@Bean
public List<String> urlsRequireAuthentication() {
    return Lists.newArrayList(
            "/auction/*"
    );
}
```

When I try to autowire a list of beans like this:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistrationBean(List<String> urlsRequireAuthentication) {
...
}
```

Not only the original list will be autowired as expected ["/auction/*"] but all registered String beans will be merged to one big list like ["/auction/*", "someString"].

I used this feature back in the time and it was useful but for this particular place I really want to only include the content of the urlsRequireAuthentication list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the method directly instead of injecting the bean as a parameter :

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistrationBean() {
    List<String> urlsRequireAuthentication = urlsRequireAuthentication();
}
```

**[@Beans documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) :**

> Typically, @Bean methods are declared within @Configuration classes.
>   **In this case, bean methods may reference other @Bean methods in the
>   same class by calling them directly. This ensures that references
>   between beans are strongly typed and navigable**. Such so-called
>   'inter-bean references' are guaranteed to respect scoping and AOP
>   semantics, just like getBean() lookups would. These are the semantics
>   known from the original 'Spring JavaConfig' project which require
>   CGLIB subclassing of each such configuration class at runtime. As a
>   consequence, @Configuration classes and their factory methods must not
>   be marked as final or private in this mode. For example:

**UPDATE**

An other way to do it would be to use the javax `@Resource` annotation. It does not work with the `@Qualifier` annotation precisely because of this feature of `@Autowired` : It is possible to provide all beans of a particular type from the  ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that expects an array of that type) :

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {

    @Resource(name="urlsRequireAuthentication")
    private List<String> urlsRequireAuthentication;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistrationBean() {
        urlsRequireAuthentication.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work but sadly in my case the someFilterRegistrationBean is created in a different configuration (in a different package in a different submodule). :(

Comment: I give you a +1 anyways because this would be a good example in a lot of cases.

Answer (score 1):

`sessionAttributeName` and `urlsRequireAuthentication` should be configuration properties and not beans. Create application.properties in the resources dir and add the following line `authentication-urls = /auction/*, /url2/*`. Now you can access your properties using the `@Value` annotation.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistrationBean(@Value("${authentication-urls}") String[] authenticationUrls) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you are using spring boot you should check out the docs for [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Qualifier](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistrationBean(@Qualifier("urlsRequireAuthentication") List<String> urlsRequireAuthentication) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it was not working with @Autowired.